How to set bridge networking for an Ubuntu Server Qemu VM in FreeBSD?
My computer is running FreeBSD 14.1 and has a wireless network wlan0.
joseccz@tigerbsd:~ $ cat /etc/os-release
NAME=FreeBSD
VERSION="14.1-RELEASE-p6"
VERSION_ID="14.1"
ID=freebsd
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
PRETTY_NAME="FreeBSD 14.1-RELEASE-p6"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:freebsd:freebsd:14.1"
HOME_URL="https://FreeBSD.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.FreeBSD.org/"


For my Qemu Ubuntu server VM I created the next tap0 and bridge0

# sysctl net.link.tap.up_on_open=1
net.link.tap.up_on_open: 0 -> 1
# ifconfig bridge0 create
# ifconfig bridge0 addm wlan0 addm tap0
# ifconfig bridge0 up

I also added ip address to the bridge:
# ifconfig bridge0 inet 192.168.0.41/24

Yet, when I run:
qemu-system-x86_64 \
-m 16384 \
-netdev tap,id=nd0,ifname=tap0,script=no -device virtio-net,netdev=nd0 \
-drive file=ubuserver.qcow2,media=disk,if=virtio

my VM starts but I get no network. Any suggestions?
